# Values don't change as they should because of recursion depth

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, depth

I am making checkers. I encountered quite a big problem. The code below describes cells king can move on.  1 cell is 100x100. He starts from (550, 50). This picture describes current_battlefield:

[image]

And this dict describes what moves AI will take

```
king_attack_moves = {
  (350, 650): [
    (550, 450), 
    (650, 350)
  ], 
  (150, 450): [
    (350, 650)
  ], 
  (550, 50): [
    (150, 450), 
    (50, 550)
  ], 
  (50, 550): [
    (250, 750)
  ]
}
```

The king is a purple checker and he has to eat right now. So, about the actual problem. If you look carefully to the king_attack_moves you will get that code doesn't find a way from cell with center at (250,750) to cells (550,450) and (650,350).

I got that the problem is enemy_positions. It doesn't clear itself after each branch. But it doesn't have to, because later I will use it, so it shold not be corrupted. This is the reason why I made temp_enemy_pos. But I stuck with it now.

I have been working for 1.5 days already and I still can't understand the reason why temp_enemy_pos doesn't go back to initial value, while it should be because of different recursion depths. So, **what temp_enemy_pos actually should be**

```
[(250, 350)]
[(250, 350), (250, 550)]
[(250, 350), (250, 550), (450, 550)]
[(250, 350), (250, 550), (450, 550)]
[(250, 350), (250, 550), (450, 550)]
[(250, 350), (250, 550), (450, 550)]
[(250, 350), (250, 550), (450, 550)]
[(250, 350), (250, 550), (450, 550)]
[(250, 350), (250, 550), (450, 550)]
[(450, 550), (150, 650)]
[(450, 550), (150, 650)]
[(450, 550), (150, 650)]
```

and **what it is**

```
[(250, 350)]
[(250, 350), (250, 550)]
[(250, 350), (250, 550), (450, 550)]
[(250, 350), (250, 550), (450, 550)]
[(250, 350), (250, 550), (450, 550)]
[(250, 350), (250, 550), (450, 550)]
[(250, 350), (250, 550), (450, 550)]
[(250, 350), (250, 550), (450, 550)]
[(250, 350), (250, 550), (450, 550)]
[(250, 350), (250, 550), (450, 550), (150, 650)]
[(250, 350), (250, 550), (450, 550), (150, 650)]
[(250, 350), (250, 550), (450, 550), (150, 650)]
```

I am sorry for all these troubles. Unfortunately, I'm a newbie so I cannot express it shorter. I hope, that at least I was able to make this understandable

Code:

```
def king_choose_attack(previous_cell_cord, enemy_checkers_keys, our_checkers_keys, cell_const, enemy_positions, temp_enemy_pos,
                       go_right_up=True,
                       go_left_down=True, go_right_down=True):
    king_attack_moves = {}
    cut_array = []
    if go_right_up:
        i = 1
        was_enemy_on_way_right_up = False
        # while current cell exist
        while (previous_cell_cord[0] + i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] - i * n) in black_cells_keys:
            # if current cell has enemy checker
            if (previous_cell_cord[0] + i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] - i * n) in enemy_checkers_keys and (
                    previous_cell_cord[0] + i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] - i * n) not in enemy_positions:
                # if next cell exist and empty
                if (previous_cell_cord[0] + (i + 1) * n, previous_cell_cord[1] - (i + 1) * n) in black_cells_keys and (
                        previous_cell_cord[0] + (i + 1) * n,
                        previous_cell_cord[1] - (i + 1) * n) not in enemy_checkers_keys and (
                        previous_cell_cord[0] + (i + 1) * n,
                        previous_cell_cord[1] - (i + 1) * n) not in our_checkers_keys:
                    enemy_positions.append((previous_cell_cord[0] + i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] - i * n))
                    temp_enemy_pos += [(previous_cell_cord[0] + i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] - i * n)]
                    was_enemy_on_way_right_up = True

                # if next cell doesn't exist or not empty
                else:
                    break

            elif (previous_cell_cord[0] + i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] - i * n) in our_checkers_keys:
                break

            # if checker already had been eaten and current cell is empty
            elif was_enemy_on_way_right_up and (
                    previous_cell_cord[0] + i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] - i * n) not in our_checkers_keys:
                cut_array.append((previous_cell_cord[0] + i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] - i * n))

                # get info related to new branch
                print(temp_enemy_pos)
                p_enemy_positions, p_king_attack_moves = king_choose_attack(
                    (previous_cell_cord[0] + i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] - i * n),
                    enemy_checkers_keys, our_checkers_keys,
                    (previous_cell_cord[0] + i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] - i * n), enemy_positions, temp_enemy_pos,
                    go_right_up=False,
                    go_left_down=False)
                king_attack_moves.update(p_king_attack_moves)
                enemy_positions = p_enemy_positions
                print(temp_enemy_pos)
                # если можно сходить
                king_attack_moves[cell_const] = cut_array
            i += 1

    if go_right_down:
        i = 1
        was_enemy_on_way_right_down = False

        # while current cell exist
        while (previous_cell_cord[0] + i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] + i * n) in black_cells_keys:
            # if current cell has enemy checker
            if (previous_cell_cord[0] + i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] + i * n) in enemy_checkers_keys and (
                    previous_cell_cord[0] + i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] + i * n) not in enemy_positions:
                # if next cell exist and empty
                if (previous_cell_cord[0] + (i + 1) * n, previous_cell_cord[1] + (i + 1) * n) in black_cells_keys and (
                        previous_cell_cord[0] + (i + 1) * n,
                        previous_cell_cord[1] + (i + 1) * n) not in enemy_checkers_keys and (
                        previous_cell_cord[0] + (i + 1) * n,
                        previous_cell_cord[1] + (i + 1) * n) not in our_checkers_keys:
                    enemy_positions.append((previous_cell_cord[0] + i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] + i * n))
                    temp_enemy_pos += [(previous_cell_cord[0] + i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] + i * n)]
                    was_enemy_on_way_right_down = True


               # if next cell doesn't exist or not empty
                else:
                    break

            elif (previous_cell_cord[0] + i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] + i * n) in our_checkers_keys:
                break

            # if checker already had been eaten and current cell is empty
            elif was_enemy_on_way_right_down and (
                    previous_cell_cord[0] + i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] + i * n) not in our_checkers_keys:
                cut_array.append((previous_cell_cord[0] + i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] + i * n))

                # get info related to new branch
                print(temp_enemy_pos)
                p_enemy_positions, p_king_attack_moves = king_choose_attack(
                    (previous_cell_cord[0] + i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] + i * n),
                    enemy_checkers_keys, our_checkers_keys,
                    (previous_cell_cord[0] + i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] + i * n), enemy_positions, temp_enemy_pos,
                    go_right_down=False)
                king_attack_moves.update(p_king_attack_moves)
                enemy_positions = p_enemy_positions
                print(temp_enemy_pos)

                king_attack_moves[cell_const] = cut_array
            i += 1
    if go_left_down:
        i = 1
        was_enemy_on_way_left_down = False
        # while current cell exist
        while (previous_cell_cord[0] - i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] + i * n) in black_cells_keys:

            # if current cell has enemy checker
            if (previous_cell_cord[0] - i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] + i * n) in enemy_checkers_keys and (
                    previous_cell_cord[0] - i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] + i * n) not in enemy_positions:
                # if next cell exist or empty
                if (previous_cell_cord[0] - (i + 1) * n, previous_cell_cord[1] + (i + 1) * n) in black_cells_keys and \
                        (previous_cell_cord[0] - (i + 1) * n,
                         previous_cell_cord[1] + (i + 1) * n) not in enemy_checkers_keys and \
                        (previous_cell_cord[0] - (i + 1) * n,
                         previous_cell_cord[1] + (i + 1) * n) not in our_checkers_keys:
                    enemy_positions.append((previous_cell_cord[0] - i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] + i * n))
                    temp_enemy_pos += [(previous_cell_cord[0] - i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] + i * n)]
                    was_enemy_on_way_left_down = True

                # if next cell doesn't exist or not empty
                else:
                    break

            # if current cell has our checker
            elif (previous_cell_cord[0] - i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] + i * n) in our_checkers_keys:
                break

            # if checker already had been eaten and current cell is empty
            elif was_enemy_on_way_left_down and (
                    previous_cell_cord[0] - i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] + i * n) not in our_checkers_keys:
                cut_array.append((previous_cell_cord[0] - i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] + i * n))
                print('temp_enemy_pos', temp_enemy_pos)
                # get info related to new branch
                p_enemy_positions, p_king_attack_moves = king_choose_attack(
                    (previous_cell_cord[0] - i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] + i * n),
                    enemy_checkers_keys, our_checkers_keys,
                    (previous_cell_cord[0] - i * n, previous_cell_cord[1] + i * n), enemy_positions, temp_enemy_pos,
                    go_right_up=False,
                    go_left_down=False)
                print(temp_enemy_pos)
                king_attack_moves.update(p_king_attack_moves)
                enemy_positions = p_enemy_positions
                king_attack_moves[cell_const] = cut_array
            i += 1
    return enemy_positions, king_attack_moves
n = 100
previous_cell_cord = (550, 50)
white_checkers_keys = [(650.0, 550.0), (150.0, 650.0), (750.0, 650.0), (50.0, 750.0), (450.0, 750.0), (650.0, 750.0),
                       (350, 450), (250, 350), (250, 550), (450, 550)]
black_checkers_keys = [(150.0, 50.0), (350.0, 50.0), (750.0, 50.0), (50.0, 150.0), (250.0, 150.0), (650.0, 150.0),
                       (150.0, 250.0), (550.0, 250.0), (750.0, 250.0), (550, 50)]
black_cells_keys = [(150.0, 50.0), (350.0, 50.0), (550.0, 50.0), (750.0, 50.0), (50.0, 150.0), (250.0, 150.0),
                    (450.0, 150.0), (650.0, 150.0), (150.0, 250.0), (350.0, 250.0), (550.0, 250.0), (750.0, 250.0),
                    (50.0, 350.0), (250.0, 350.0), (450.0, 350.0), (650.0, 350.0), (150.0, 450.0), (350.0, 450.0),
                    (550.0, 450.0), (750.0, 450.0), (50.0, 550.0), (250.0, 550.0), (450.0, 550.0), (650.0, 550.0),
                    (150.0, 650.0), (350.0, 650.0), (550.0, 650.0), (750.0, 650.0), (50.0, 750.0), (250.0, 750.0),
                    (450.0, 750.0), (650.0, 750.0)]
white_positions, king_attack_moves = king_choose_attack(
    previous_cell_cord,
    white_checkers_keys,
    black_checkers_keys, previous_cell_cord, [], [])
```

Comment: if each cell is 100x100 square then the purple circle is [550, 150] and not [550, 50] as stated in the question.  Can you confirm that this is correct or advise...?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I posted a little wrong king_attack_moves. But everything else related to the king_attack_moves is right

Comment: So, it actually starts from (450,150)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic kind of bug.  The problem is that you pass `enemy_positions`.  Which means that the object is shared between the recursive call and the previous.  So what happens in the recursive call is seen in the parent.

You either need to `.copy()` it, or else you need to manually fix it back to being the previous on the way out of the call.  Of the two, `.copy()` is much more expensive but also simpler and more reliable.